# Slide View Controller

Tags: swift, uitableview, swift3

I managed to make a slide menu controller programmatically. I am trying to add a transition in the tableViewController for when you click a label to close the menu with an animation that will make the tableView full screen for 0.2sec and then will close the menu. This will give time to change the view by the button clicked and will look nice. Did that in didSelectRowAtIndexPath. It works!

```
tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)
```

Because I am only opening the menu 80% of the screen I am shifting the contentView of the cell to show up in that 80% of the screen. When the animation begins in didSelectRowAtIndexPath I am shifting back to 0 so I will not see a space on the left of the tableView, like so:

```
tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, menuWidthGap, 0, -menuWidthGap)
```

Now, when I click the button again it remains like that. What can I do for when I am clicking the button again to go back to the initial state of the contentView.

This is my tableView:

```
    import UIKit

class MenuLeftVC: UITableViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Initialize the window
        let window = UIWindow.init(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        window.makeKeyAndVisible()

        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow
        navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = true

        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false

        tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")



    }


    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(true)
        print("did apear")
        tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, menuWidthGap, 0, -menuWidthGap)
    }

    func selectCell() {
        print("selected cell - >")

        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name("SelectedCell"), object: nil)
    }

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 20
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell")!
        cell.contentView.reloadInputViews()

        cell.isSelected = false
        tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, menuWidthGap, 0, -menuWidthGap)


        cell.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow
        cell.textLabel?.text = "Daim Boy"


        return cell
    }


    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let selectedCell:UITableViewCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)!
        selectedCell.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red

        selectedCell.isSelected = false

        if selectedCell.isSelected == true {
        print("selection")
        if selectedCell.textLabel?.text == "Daim Boy" {
            print("cell is selected")
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {
                tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, menuWidthGap, 0, -menuWidthGap)
                self.selectCell()
                //selectedCell.isSelected = false

            })

        }

        }


    }






}
```

Comment: I am not sure how you implemented the slideshow, but it sounds like you might want to use a `UICollectionView` instead of a `UITableView`, as it brings sliding and transitions for free.

Comment: I think you should have a look in view controller transitions.

Comment: Thanks anyway, but It's got nothing to do with ViewController animation. I have 2 content views. One of them holds a menu and another one holds a view controller. When I press a menu item didSelectCell is triggered and I have that animation that will shift contentView. I will place the full code for better understanding.

Comment: just changed the brief guys if you can have a look again.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix the issue: (it was so simple) I am just calling viewWillAppear where I placed the code to make the layout like in the beginning with DispatchQue at the end of the function:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let selectedCell:UITableViewCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)!
    selectedCell.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red

    selectedCell.isSelected = false

    if selectedCell.isSelected == true {
    print("selection")
    if selectedCell.textLabel?.text == "Daim Boy" {
        print("cell is selected")
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {
            tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)
            self.selectCell()
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1.0, execute: { 
                self.viewWillAppear(true)
            })

            //selectedCell.isSelected = false

        })

    }

    }


}
```

And viewWillAppear contains:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(true)
    print("will appear")
    tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, menuWidthGap, 0, -menuWidthGap)

}
```